# Azure App service - .Net Core - Failed to start application /LM/W3SVC/###/ROOT, ErrorCode "0x800700c1"

Tags: .net-core, 64-bit, azure-web-app-service

After deploying to a newly created Azure App Service, I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure
```

eventlog.xml shows these two lines:

```
<Data>Failed to start application '/LM/W3SVC/1773510456/ROOT', ErrorCode '0x800700c1'.</Data>
```

And

```
<Data>Could not find inprocess request handler. Captured output from invoking hostfxr: </Data>
```

I am deploying a 64 bit Web Api (`<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` inside the csproj).

Answer (score 0):

Googling the errors reveals that it's related to a 64bit/32bit mismatch. Azure App Service is set to 32 bit, this needs to be changed. Copied and modified from [AspNetCore.Docs Issue 13013](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/13013#issuecomment-505964825) :

> Azure App Service does have both the 32- and 64-bit runtimes available
>   since .NET Core 2.2 was released. To set the Platform to 64
>   Bit, go to the **App Service > Configuration > General settings > Platform settings > Platform > 64 bit**. Note that you need to have a Basic or higher service app plan.